Using present perfect with "for"
Someone is impressed by my dancing skills. I imagine I could replay to them using present perfect

Oh it's because I have taken dance classes.

It might be I take them no more I just emphasize my experience. What if I add "for"?

Oh it is because I have been taking dance classes for 2 years

Do we have two meanings? Either I take no more clases I just highlight that event from my life using perfect or I still take them? Or only one interpretetion is posssible here?

Present perfect "have taken" means that you took classes in the past. It usually implies that you're no longer taking them. You can also say simply:

Oh, it's because I took dance classes.

Present perfect continuous "have been taking" means you were taking classes in the past, and you're still taking them. Adding "for two years" means that you started taking them two years ago.

Oh it's because I have taken dance classes for 2 years. Now?

That's a little ambiguous. Some will interpret it the same as "have been taking dance classes for 2 years", others may think it means you took 2 years of classes sometime in the past. You could be clearer with "I have taken dance classes for the past 2 years". But "have been taking" is more idiomatic.

English is very flexible about this, and there's lots of overlap in meaning.

this might mean I take them no more "Oh it's because I have taken dance classes for 2 years. " right?  What about this Oh it's because I have been  taking dance classes for 2 years. ?

I already answered that in my second paragraph.

I don't think that saying for instance "I have working hard"  stricly implies that I still do it

*”I have working hard” is not a valid English sentence.

Obviously there's "been" sorry

"I've been working hard for two hours" (I'm still working.) "I've been working hard today. I spent two hours digging the garden this morning."

@KateBunting  I have played football for 2 years- either I still play or emphasize my previois experience and don't play anymore. I have been playing for 2 years- only one possibility I still play. Correct?

Ye...es - but I played football for two years would be much more idiomatic if you no longer play.


You're such a good dancer!
-- I take dance classes.
-- I am taking dance classes.
-- I have been taking dance classes.
-- I have taken dance classes.
-- I took dance classes.

take and am taking entail the meanining that these classes are ongoing in the present.
have been taking suggests but does not entail that the classes are still ongoing.
have taken suggests but does not entail that the classes are not still ongoing
took entails that those classes  happened in the past and are not ongoing
